# OTA_AirPriceRQ in Sabre AIr booking

Tags: soap

Can any one help me on the OTA_AirPriceRQ request. I want to know the options which I can include with it so that i can get a success response.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:mes="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:v3="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_7">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <sec:Security>
              <sec:BinarySecurityToken>Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3273332406989210493!448034!0!1</sec:BinarySecurityToken>
      </sec:Security>
      <mes:MessageHeader >
         <mes:From>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
                        <mes:PartyId mes:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">Traform</mes:PartyId>        
                   </mes:From>
         <mes:To>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
           <mes:PartyId mes:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">Sabre</mes:PartyId>

         </mes:To>
         <mes:CPAId>VJ6I</mes:CPAId>
<mes:ConversationId>Traform</mes:ConversationId>
                  <mes:Service mes:type="OTA">EnhancedAirBookRQ</mes:Service>
       <mes:Action>EnhancedAirBookRQ</mes:Action>
         <mes:MessageData>
           <mes:MessageId>1000</mes:MessageId>
            <mes:Timestamp>2017-05-22T17:28</mes:Timestamp> 
                   </mes:MessageData>
      </mes:MessageHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
      <v3:EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_7" version="3.7.0" HaltOnError="true">

         <v3:OTA_AirBookRQ>

            <v3:OriginDestinationInformation>

               <v3:FlightSegment  DepartureDateTime="2017-11-21T17:05" FlightNumber="9392"
               NumberInParty="1" 
               ResBookDesigCode="F" Status="QF">
                  <v3:DestinationLocation LocationCode="LHR"/>

                  <v3:MarketingAirline Code="MH" FlightNumber="9392"/>

                  <v3:OriginLocation LocationCode="DFW"/>
               </v3:FlightSegment>
            </v3:OriginDestinationInformation>

<RedisplayReservation NumAttempts="2" WaitInterval="5000"/>
         </v3:OTA_AirBookRQ> 
<v3:OTA_AirPriceRQ>
        <v3:PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
          <v3:OptionalQualifiers>
            <v3:PricingQualifiers>
            <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />

              </v3:PricingQualifiers>    
 </v3:OptionalQualifiers>
        </v3:PriceRequestInformation>
      </v3:OTA_AirPriceRQ>
      </v3:EnhancedAirBookRQ>

   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
See below complete Enhanced Air Book request  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <EnhancedAirBookRQ version="3.7.0" HaltOnError="true">
       <OTA_AirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_7">
          <HaltOnStatus Code="NN" />
          <HaltOnStatus Code="UC" />
          <HaltOnStatus Code="NO" />
          <HaltOnStatus Code="US" />
          <OriginDestinationInformation>
             <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2017-06-01T15:40" FlightNumber="4793" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="K" Status="NN">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="CDG" />
                <Equipment AirEquipType="77W" />
                <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="639" />
                <MarriageGrp>O</MarriageGrp>
                <OperatingAirline Code="AF" />
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="IAH" />
             </FlightSegment>
             <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2017-06-02T11:35" FlightNumber="123" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="K" Status="NN">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
                <Equipment AirEquipType="333" />
                <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="123" />
                <MarriageGrp>I</MarriageGrp>
                <OperatingAirline Code="9W" />
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="CDG" />
             </FlightSegment>
             <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2017-06-03T05:30" FlightNumber="341" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="K" Status="NN">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BDQ" />
                <Equipment AirEquipType="738" />
                <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="341" />
                <MarriageGrp>I</MarriageGrp>
                <OperatingAirline Code="9W" />
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
             </FlightSegment>
             <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2017-06-06T20:55" FlightNumber="344" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="O" Status="NN">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
                <Equipment AirEquipType="738" />
                <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="344" />
                <MarriageGrp>O</MarriageGrp>
                <OperatingAirline Code="9W" />
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="BDQ" />
             </FlightSegment>
             <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2017-06-07T02:25" FlightNumber="3288" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="V" Status="NN">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="AMS" />
                <Equipment AirEquipType="333" />
                <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="3288" />
                <MarriageGrp>I</MarriageGrp>
                <OperatingAirline Code="9W" />
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
             </FlightSegment>
             <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2017-06-07T10:00" FlightNumber="8803" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="V" Status="NN">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="IAH" />
                <Equipment AirEquipType="74E" />
                <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="661" />
                <MarriageGrp>I</MarriageGrp>
                <OperatingAirline Code="KL" />
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="AMS" />
             </FlightSegment>
          </OriginDestinationInformation>
          <RedisplayReservation NumAttempts="2" WaitInterval="5000" />
       </OTA_AirBookRQ>
       <OTA_AirPriceRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_7">
          <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
             <OptionalQualifiers>
                <FlightQualifiers>
                   <VendorPrefs>
                      <Airline Code="9W" />
                   </VendorPrefs>
                </FlightQualifiers>
                <MiscQualifiers>
                   <Commission Amount="0.00" />
                </MiscQualifiers>
                <PricingQualifiers CurrencyCode="USD">
                   <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
                   <PassengerType Code="INF" Quantity="1" />
                   <PassengerType Code="CNN" Quantity="1" />
                </PricingQualifiers>
             </OptionalQualifiers>
          </PriceRequestInformation>
       </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
       <PostProcessing xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_7">
          <RedisplayReservation WaitInterval="5000" UnmaskCreditCard="true" />
       </PostProcessing>
    </EnhancedAirBookRQ>
```